# Where do I need to ask question about Google Earth Engine?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I try to learn how to use Google Earth engine (GEE) for GIS and I don't know where to ask my questions. There are two solutions:

- [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-engine) where the TAG [google-earth-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-engine) is available
- [SE GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-engine?tab=Active) which seems to be more accurate with the `gee` tag as well

Why are the GEE-related question not moved to the appropriate SE community? Where do I need to ask my questions?

I don't even know if I'm asking this question in the right place...

Comment: None. Websites from Stack Community isn't a place for learning a new thing, i suggest you to search someplace else. Here is a place to answer your question, but you need some experience or learning with what you want

Comment: @riki481 that's not true at all. By Asking, and answering, and reading the material here we **all** learn (apart from those users that come here with the "I need the answer, kthx goodbye" attitude). if the OP can make a qusetion that is programming related, then it could likely be on topic for SO.

Comment: Of course it's for usage and specific questions, I won't ask "how to use GIS ?". No the point here is that GIS are on the edge as you always use programming but there is a specific community. Which leads to the split of the community and a duplication of many questions

Comment: @riki481 at the end of the day, a well asked question deserves an answer. I will never not answer a question if I see the asker has put in good effort. SO might be classed (maybe an outdated notion) as an experts area, but we have never turned down new learners who follow the question asking rules. I learn new things all the time on the Stack network, but experience is not needed in a technology in order to ask a question.

Comment: @Larnu But not from zero, and that's the point. If you want to ask something about: "i'm new in programming, where should i get started? what programming language is easy to learn?" That person probably will have the question closed and negativaded. The point is that you need knowledge before asking anything on Stack websites, and that's why he shouldn't ask for now

Comment: That question example you give is completely off topic for SO. And no, you don't *need* a knowledge base, but you *do* need to make the effort. If someone started off on a SQL tutorial, and got stuck, they could easily still write an on topic question, and they would still learn from it. It's not a tutorial site, no, but it certainly can aid those working through tutorials.

Comment: This is a bit off topic because we don't know the technical aspects of OP's questions they want to potentially ask. What really matters is, are the questions of a programming nature? Stack Overflow. And if they are not, where do the questions go? Let's assume that they are good questions and focus on the question at hand.

Comment: Possibly [gis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/), which is described as *"Geographic Information Systems is a question and answer site for people interested in GIS, Remote Sensing, Photogrammetry, Geodesy and Surveying, as well as Programming/Databases specific to the aforementioned."*.

Comment: Last month, SO got 23 questions with that tag, only 4 got an answer.  At gis.se there were 131 questions, 79 got an answer.  Well, that makes it easy to choose.

Comment: but would'nt it be smart to prevent people to use this tag and lead them to gis.se ? or adding an alert in the description of the tag that there is a dedicated community ?

Comment: @PierrickRambaud there are a lot sites with overlapping scopes as you found.  In a lot of cases, the right site is a personal choice driven by (1) your comfort level with the site and the expectations of the site (2) the perspective of the answerers that you are seeking.  If you are looking for an answer from a programmer, you are definately going to find one on SO.  But you may or may not find one on GIS.SE.  Likewise, if you want an answer from a GIS Professional then you are more likely going to find one on GIS.SE.  Same with other sites that overlap with SO.